# How to check in the next 'head' in OCaml is empty?

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm new at OCaml (and still a novice in learning programming in general) and I have a quick question about checking what kind of string the next element in the string list is.

I want it to put a separator between each element of the string (except for the last one), but I can't figure out how to make the program 'know' that the last element is the last element.

Here is my code as it is now:

```
let rec join (separator: string) (l : string list) : string = 
 begin match l with
    | []->""
    | head::head2::list-> if head2=[] then head^(join separator list) else head^separator^(join separator list)
 end


let test () : bool =
 (join "," ["a";"b";"c"]) = "a,b,c"
;; run_test "test_join1" test
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're almost there. The idea is breaking down the list in three cases where it has 0, 1 or at least 2 elements. When the list has more than one element, you're safe to insert `separator` into the output string:

```
let rec join (separator: string) (l : string list) : string =   
   begin match l with
    | [] -> ""
    | head::[] -> head
    | head::list-> head^separator^(join separator list)  
   end
```

I have several comments about your function:

- Type annotation is redundant. Because `(^)` is string concatenation operator, the type checker can infer types of `separator`, `l` and the output of the function easily.
- No need to use `begin/and` pair. Since you have only one level of pattern matching, there is no confusion to the compiler.
- You could use `function` to eliminate `match l with` part.

Therefore, your code could be shortened as:

```
let rec join sep l = 
    match l with
    | [] -> ""
    | x::[] -> x
    | x::xs -> x ^ sep ^ join sep xs
```

or even more concise:

```
 let rec join sep = function
    | [] -> ""
    | x::[] -> x
    | x::xs -> x ^ sep ^ join sep xs
```

Answer (score 8):

The empty list is `[]`, the list with one element is `[h]` and the list with at least one element is `h::t`. So your function can be written as:

```
let rec join separator = function
  | []   -> ""
  | [h]  -> h
  | h::t -> h ^ separator ^ join separator t
```